# Adding multiple context in a try except situation

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to import some data into my HTML using context
right now my code is the following and is working great. 
I am using a Try/Except because a project is not always created and kwargs['pk1']) does not always exist:

my working code:

```
class ProjectDetailView(generic.DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project_details.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(Project,id=self.kwargs['pk1'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            team_name = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
            context['team_name'] = team_name
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return context
```

THe thing is I would like to add another key pair to that context and from there I always get an

```
Reverse for 'team_select' with keyword arguments '{'pk1': ''}' not found.   
1 pattern(s) tried: ['website/project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/linkteam2/$']
```

I tried :

```
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            team_name = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
            team_score = get_team_cohesivenss_score(self)
            m_context = {'team_name':team_name,
                         'team_score':team_score
                        }
            context = m_context
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return context
```

any idea?

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/website/project/2/

Django Version: 1.11.5
Python Version: 3.6.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'registration',
 'website',
 'django_extensions',
 'crispy_forms',
 'survey',
 'bootstrapform',
 'rosetta',
 'rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /Users/raphaelbendenoun/Documents/Django Projects/Authentication_project/website/templates/projectdetailtemp/noteamcreated.html, error at line 8
   Reverse for 'team_select' with keyword arguments '{'pk1': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['website/project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/linkteam2/$']   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : <div class="invite-team">
   3 :   <div class="jumbotron greenback">
   4 :     <div class="jumbo-text">
   5 :       <h7>Your project has been created, It is time to link a team or create a new for your project</h3>
   6 :     </div>
   7 :       <div class="jumbo-button">
   8 :         <a href=" {% url 'website:team_select' pk1=project.id %} " class="btn btn-secondary" role="button"><span class="fa fa-link"></span>   Link an existing team</a>
   9 :         <a href="{% url 'website:add_team' pk1=project.id %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span>   Create a new team</a>
   10 :       </div>
   11 :   </div>
   12 : </div>
   13 : 

Traceback:

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  107.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  84.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  322.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  216.                 return template.render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                 return self._render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  458.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  497.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /website/project/2/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'team_select' with keyword arguments '{'pk1': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['website/project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/linkteam2/$']
```

Comment: You need to show the code that is causing that error.

Comment: This is the code that is causing the error .. When I tried the second version with m_context I get that error .. even without adding the second key pair, just by changing context['team_name'] = team_name to context = { 'team_name' : team_name} I get the error ;(

Comment: No it isn't. Nothing in the code you have shown is calling `reverse()`. You need to show the code that is, or at least the full traceback so that we can see where the error is occurring.

Comment: I know .. but this is the case when I change it to what I tried it shows the error if I undo to what it is context['team_name'] = team_name it is ok .. I added the traceback in the post